# PostgreSQL pgbench error "pgbench: fatal: could not count number of branches: ERROR: relation "pgbench_branches" does not exist"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14, pgbench

I am getting error like "**pgbench: fatal: could not count number of branches: ERROR:  relation "pgbench_branches" does not exist**" when i ran the commmand "**pgbench -c 20 -t 1000 -C -f d:\test_postgres\script.sql -p 5432 -U postgres -S Shiftlog**" in windows command prompt.

-c is number of current clients
-t number of transactions per clients
-C Close the connection afer every transaction
-f run/execute the specified file
-p Port number of postgre instance
-S Database name in the postgre instance

I haven't stored the pgbench tables in my db(i.e. Shiftlog). Because i don't know the process to get these tables in windows postgres environment. Even though i specified the script file why pgbench is using the TPC-B file for the excurtion?.

```
D:\test_postgres>pgbench -c 20 -t 1000 -C -f d:\test_postgres\script.sql -p 5432 -U postgres -S Shiftlog
Password:
pgbench (14.5)
pgbench: fatal: could not count number of branches: ERROR:  relation "pgbench_branches" does not exist
LINE 1: select count(*) from pgbench_branches
                             ^
pgbench: Perhaps you need to do initialization ("pgbench -i") in database "Shiftlog"

D:\test_postgres>
```

Could you please help me to resolve this problem. Thank you so much for your support. Please check below image for the commands of sql script file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eepwH.jpg)

Comment: "-S Database name in the postgre instance"  That is not what `-S` does.

Comment: Thank you for reply @jjanes. What you said is corrrect. -S behaviour is as following.

-S select-only. Run built-in select-only script.

Once i change query as like below I could be able to run the following command in cmd. 

**pgbench -c 20 -t 10 -C -f d:\test_postgres\script.sql -p 5432 -U postgres Shiftlog**

I am getting following warrings in command prompt. If you have any idea please let me know how can i avoide the followng warrnings. 

pgbench (14.5)
starting vacuum...pgbench: error: ERROR:  relation "pgbench_branches" does not exist
pgbench: (ignoring this error and

Comment: If you specify `-n`, then it won't try to vacuum the default tables, and so won't generate the warning.

Comment: Thank you @jjanes. After your suggestions. I am not getting the warrnings. It helped.